During WWII, why was internment/incarceration rate of Japanese Americans so much higher than German Americans?
In terms of percentages, roughly 1% (11,000) of German Americans were incarcerated, while roughly 80% (110,000) of Japanese Americans were (an order of magnitude difference in absolute terms). Since the USA was at war with both of these parent nations in WWII, I don't really understand why there was such a huge difference.

Citations from wiki:

The government examined the cases of German nationals individually, and detained relatively few in internment camps run by the Department of Justice, as related to its responsibilities under the Alien Enemies Act. To a much lesser extent, some ethnic German US citizens were classified as suspect after due process and also detained.
... the United States detained [in camps] at least 11,000 ethnic Germans ... (out of ~ 1.2 million ... )

timeline: (unclear)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment_of_German_Americans
And

About 80% (i.e. 110,000 people) of the Japanese-American people who lived in the continental United States were forced to leave their homes and live in internment camps. Approximately two-thirds of the detainees were United States citizens.

timeline: From February 19, 1942 to December 18, 1944.
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_American_internment
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment_of_Japanese_Americans

Please ask this question on History SE. See, Why were there no internment camps for German-American citizens in USA during WW2?.

This isn't a SE.Politics question.  At a guess, besides the answers in the SE.History link:  1) racism 2) the actually rather treacherous nature of Pearl Harbor 3) the US had "experimented" with interning Germans in WW1 - and likely found it not that useful.  4) the officer in charge of the policy on the West Coast specifically went "above and beyond" what his instructions were (see item #1). 5) the SE.History answer says there were more, and more influential, German immigrants (also, see item #1). Still, repeat after me:  history,history,history.

Just to point out the obvious, neither the Germans nor the Italians attacked the US on US soil. The Japanese specifically went after the US fleets in Hawaii, and thus were considered a more direct threat.

Large part of the USA is German by origin, and they remembered it much better 80 years ago. A lot of USA citizen still can speak on German or it is their first foreign language on family traditional reason. I don't think that your 1million of German Americans is correct, I do not know the exact number but I think it might be between 50 and 100millions. Which is also an answer, they could not imprison themselves.

The short answer is racism. German-Americans were presumed to have loyally assimilated into polite white American society (Italians only slightly less so) and the Japanese-Americans were not. The decisonmakers in power simply distrusted the Japanese more than Germans.
John DeWitt, the Army general in charge of carrying out Roosevelt's executive order (which was technically colorblind), testified before Congress and said the following, on the record:

I don't want any of them here. They are a dangerous element. There is
no way to determine their loyalty... It makes no difference whether he
is an American citizen, he is still a Japanese. American citizenship
does not necessarily determine loyalty. You
needn’t worry about the Italians at all except in certain cases. Also, the same for the Germans
except in individual cases. But we must worry about the
Japanese all the time until he is wiped off the map.

Quite bluntly, if you substitute out "American" and "Japanese," for "German" and "Jew," this could be a passage from Mein Kampf.
The other answer is that it was logistically much easier to corral a larger proportion of Japanese than Germans and Italians. There were about 127,000 Japanese-Americans living in the U.S. at the time of WWII, compared to 1.2 million German-born Americans: that's before counting the millions upon millions more of Americans who had parents or grandparents from Germany. And of course many German-Americans blended in seamlessly with their white neighbors in a way the Japanese never could.

Well, the German-Americans blended in part because WW1 necessitated it. My grandmother came from a German-American family in the midwest, and they initially spoke German at home as did many others. German language newspapers were quite common. Then came WW1 and they family stopped speaking German and the German language newspapers etc. went away.
